# OpenLayers feature opacity vs zIndex

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 4.6.5. I have a VectorLayer with a couple of circle features that have the same zIndex. The problem is, that the features texts are overlapping although I've set the the opacity of the text and the fill to 1.0. The following image shows two circle features with texts '3' and '4' overlapping. I want that one circle is entirely below the other. It doesn't matter which one but I cannot change the zIndex.

[image: overlapping]

```
var markerStyle = (feature: Feature) => new Style({
    text: new Text({
      text: feature.get('text'),
      font: 'Normal 8px Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif',
      fill: new Fill({color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)'})
    }),
    image: new Circle({
      radius: 10,
      fill: new Fill({color: rgba(193, 0, 31, 1.0)}),
      stroke: new Stroke({color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)', width: 1}),
    }),
    zIndex: 10
  });
```

So basically the two features have the same style but different texts. Interestingly enough I have other circle features that overlap only partially and the stroke color of one circle is always below the other circle (i.e. not visible), but the text is not. I cannot change the zIndex as there are too many different features.

Comment: It is your labels that are still visible not your circle. Labels are (usually) drawn last so as not to be hidden by other markers.

Comment: @IanTurton So there is no way around changing zIndex in my case?

Comment: I don't think Z index will help either but I'm not really an OpenLayers styling expert

Comment: specifying `backgroundFill: new Fill({color: rgba(193, 0, 31, 1.0)})` for the text may produce the desired effect

Comment: backgroundFill would need to be used in conjunction with padding

Comment: Thanks @Mike. It set a background box around the text label and made it a little bit better.